# android:Graphics memory is extremly high

Tags: android, memory-leaks

The bug is reported by someone else, I have no idea the steps, but got the meminfo dumped, and the hprof file.

[image]

It seems the Graphics taking about 1G bytes.... From the [android doc](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/memory-profiler#how-counted), it says Graphics is

> Memory used for graphics buffer queues to display pixels to the
>   screen, including GL surfaces, GL textures, and so on. (Note that this
>   is memory shared with the CPU, not dedicated GPU memory.)

So how app caused taking so much graphics buffer, does because app have hold some bitmaps I dont know?

The memory leak shown by the hprof file is much less than 1G bytes.

[image]

Any clues about the Graphics high memory comsumption?